# How to scroll drag&drop-able objects based solely on their current position on the stage at the time the user scrolls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, scroll

I'm working in Flash with Actionscript 3. I have a class of objects. Let's say the class is called "apple." At runtime, a number of instances of "apple" are generated on the left half of the stage. Every instance of "apple" can be dragged and dropped anywhere on the stage. Both the left and right halves of the stage have other art on them. What I am trying to construct is some mechanism by which the user can scroll up and down on ONLY the right (as in opposed to left) half of the stage, so that both the art on the right half of the stage and all instances of "apple" currently on the right half of the stage move in unison, while the art and instances of "apple" on the left half of the stage remain stationary. Any advice at all on what kinds of solutions I should be looking into would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In short: You can use `hitTestObject` to test whether or not the currently dragged/dropped apple ended up on the right side of the screen. Create an array and store the instancenames of the apples on the right side. When the right side scrolls, move the apples in the array accordingly. This can be done by tracking y-coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm green to actionscript so this is extremely helpful.